# parsing attribute from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xmldocument

I'm trying to parse the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GC>
  <CREATED>01/23/2014 16:10:18</CREATED>
  <DATA>
    <CONTAINER name="home" type="xml" version="1.1.0.0">
      <HEADER>
        <ATTRIBUTE name="lang" value="EN" />
        <ATTRIBUTE name="destination" value="UK" />
      </HEADER>
    </CONTAINER>
  </DATA>
</GC>
```

How do I go about finding the **value** when **name="lang"**?

So far I have this:

```
XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.Load(@path);
XmlNode node = Doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/GC/DATA/CONTAINER/HEADER/ATTRIBUTE/NAME");
string SI = node.Attributes["lang"].InnerText;
```

Doesn't seem to work unfortunately, could use some help. Many thanks.

Comment: The name of the attribute is `name` - the value is `lang`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  `lang` *is* the inner text.  Are you trying to find the value of `name`?

Comment: I want to find out what **value** contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
XmlNode node = 
 Doc.SelectSingleNode("/GC/DATA/CONTAINER/HEADER/ATTRIBUTE[@name = 'lang']/@value");
string SI = node.InnerText;
```

And I would advise using a null check:

```
XmlNode node = 
 Doc.SelectSingleNode("/GC/DATA/CONTAINER/HEADER/ATTRIBUTE[@name = 'lang']/@value");
string SI = null;
if(node != null)
{
    SI = node.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: It should be @name = 'lang'

Answer (score 0):

With using `LINQ to XML` you can get it like this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");
var element = xDoc.Descendans("ATTRIBUTE").First();
var nameAttribute = (string)element.Attribute("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the value of the attribute in the ATTRIBUTE tag which has name == lang:

```
XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.Load(@path);
XmlNode node = Doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/GC/DATA/CONTAINER/HEADER/ATTRIBUTE[@name='lang']");
string SI = node.Attributes["value"].InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    XmlNode node = Doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/GC/DATA/CONTAINER/HEADER/ATTRIBUTE[@name='lang']");
    string SI = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
```